# How to import GSS files into GWT HTML file

Tags: html, css, gwt

Using this guide: http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/gss_migration.html I converted all my CSS files to GSS. 2 of my CSS were loaded via the entry point HTML file index.html:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="gwt.css">
```

Now that those 2 files are GSS files, how do I include them in the project? I tried simply doing those 2 lines above with the GSS files, and while they do get loaded, some things don't work properly, such as custom styling on checkboxes.

Am I doing this right? I'd like those 2 files above to have access to GSS features, but I feel like this type of import only sees the files as CSS files with the wrong extension.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you missed some important things.

GSS is a compile step with optimization and dead "code" removal. The be able to do this, you will have to create a Bundle and a GssResource. You cannot include it in the HTML-file. All is done vie interfaces in your code.

In you linked gss migration file, there is a chapter "Prerequisites".

Take a look at the [ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) tutorial.

Comment: The Pre-requisites chapter doesn't say anything about this... only that you can't mix css and gss in a single ClientBundle. I understand how to use ClientBundles, but I didn't think it quite applied here. The gwt.css file, for example, has all my customizations to the default gwt classes, so it's quite long. In a ClientBundle, you have to specify an accessor method for each CSS class, but I don't need to access these. They just need to be injected into the html everytime a page loads.

Comment: You will need a compile step to use *.gss files. As far as I know there is no way of using gss-files without using ClientBundles.

Comment: You can just use Closure Stylesheets. Files loaded that way are independent of whether you use GWT or not.